# Pass php variable in header with post

Tags: php

I would like to pass a php variable in header with post, it's easy with get but i want to use post to hide it in the url .

**page 1**

```
$password=$tab['password_view'];
header("location:page2.php");
```

**page 2**

```
echo $password;
```

Comment: You can't. Use sessions instead.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: Lordie, don't pass passwords in sessions or in header, or anywhere else than a safe area/method. You are asking for T-R-O-U-B-L-E.

Comment: like sessions hijacking no longer exists @rjdown I would NEVER recommend that.

Answer (score 0):

PAGE 1:

```
<?php

session_start();
$_SESSION['my_saved_variable'] = $my_local_variable;
```

PAGE 2:

```
<?php

session_start();
echo $_SESSION['my_saved_variable'];
```

Probably a good idea to check of the session variable exists before using it as well.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest this. Ever heard of session hijacking? Any which way, not recommended.

Comment: I wouldn't do it for passwords either. Just illustrating how to use a session variable to persist variables across page fetches.